Efficiently Handling Large-Scale Static Site Generation in Next.js
I'm working on a Next.js project that involves building a large number of pages (hundreds to thousands) at build time.
Our automated CI/CD process, which is standard across my company, runs next build on every deployment to every environment.
We value Next.js static site generation mainly for SEO reasons, but is also useful for performance and reducing the load on the server.
Challenges
Re-building every page for every deployment has been okay up until now, but we're reaching a scale of content where:

our pipelines are becoming slower,
we're starting to hit internal and 3rd-party rate limits, which (depending on our approach) either causes the build to fail or builds the site with missing content.

Questions

Are there any specific strategies within Next.js to optimize the build process for a large number of pages?
Is there a recommended way of caching older content between build pipelines so it doesn't need to be rebuilt?
If so, can this be achieved purely in the application layer? Or is this an infrastructure problem?
Should we add delays to ensure we stay under rate limits and become comfortable with the longer build times?

